Excel LET function to return filtered values of various size based on a criteria row by row
I am working with this data set:

What I need is to return the list of values corresponding to to each unique category. Seems straight forward and I generated this using excel formula
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER($B$2:$B$11,$A$2:$A$11=D2))) 

by dragging down. Here's the output:

What I need eventually is to use the list of values for each of the categories, as a variable of LET function, to output everything all at once as a part of bigger formula. I have tested this set of solutions:

=LET(AllCategories,$A$2:$A$11,values,$B$2:$B$11,myCategories,D2:D4,output,MAP(myCategories,LAMBDA(x,TRANSPOSE(FILTER(values,AllCategories=x)))),output)

=LET(categories,D2:D5,BYROW(categories,LAMBDA(category,HSTACK(category,FILTER($B$2:$B$11,$A$2:$A$11=category)))))

=LET( uniqueCategories, UNIQUE(A2:A11), BYROW(uniqueCategories, LAMBDA(category, HSTACK(category, TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B2:B11, A2:A11=category))))) )

=LET(uniqueCategories,UNIQUE(A2:A11),valuesList,MAP(uniqueCategories, LAMBDA(category, HSTACK(category, FILTER($B$2:$B$11, $A$2:$A$11=category)))), valuesList)


The goal of formulas 1-4 was to go by each unique category row by row, and return values based on category in col A. In each case I have got the #CALC! as a result.
Looking for a help here. I've googled the problem, eployed ( :) ) chatGPT to try to figure it out and still cannot solve it.

using REDUCE/LAMBDA:
=IFERROR(DROP(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(A2:A11),LAMBDA(z,y,VSTACK(z,HSTACK(y,TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B2:B11,A2:A11=y)))))),1),"")



This is great. Thank you! is there a way to add another variable that would be used row by row and return the percentile rank in the set of data?
f.e. u = 1, percentile rank among 1 and 2, then g =3, what's percentile rank in that set.

@barszczula new questions get new posts.  Please ask a new question with the relevant data, expected output, and what you have tried.  If this answered the question posted here, please considering marking this answer as correct by click the check mark by the answer as it will close this question.

posted a new questions with follow up task: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78972951/excel-let-lambda-function-to-return-category-percentile-rank
Scott, Please let me know if you are able to debug the formula
