Excel LET LAMBDA function to return category percentile rank
I am working with this data set:



ids
Cat
Val




u1
u
1


u2
u
2


g3
g
3


g4
g
4


g5
g
5


i6
i
6


i7
i
7


i8
i
8


i9
i
9


i10
i
10



I need the the percentile ranks for categories of my IDS. I need to have this in a LET function, as I want to use it as a part of a bigger formula.
Here is what I tested:

Formula: =LET(ids,E2:E4,cats,XLOOKUP(ids,$A$2:$A$11,$B$2:$B$11,""),vals,XLOOKUP(ids,$A$2:$A$11,$C$2:$C$11,""),output,BYROW(cats,LAMBDA(x,PERCENTRANK(FILTER(vals,cats=x),val))),output)
Any ideas why LAMBDA does not work would be appreciated.

The #Name? error is because you use val rather than vals in the last parameter of PERCENTRANK.  After correcting that you'll get a #CALC! error.

I'm not sure why you're using the BYROW, you can just do PERCENT.RANG(vals;vals); or am I missing something in the bigger picture?

A) can you please confirm the function that you've meat? I cannot find anything like 'PERCENT.RANG(vals;vals)' in excel
B) there is couple of ids I want to extract from database and call the ranks within their peer groups, rather than ranks vs. the whole database

Match in Two Columns Using MAP

This is a case when using BYROW would be far more complicated than using MAP.
Note that MSDocs claims the new PERCENTRANK functions offer more precision.

=LET(sData,A2:C11,siCol,1,scCol,2,svCol,3,
        di,E2:E4,significance,1,if_not_found,"",
    si,CHOOSECOLS(sData,siCol),
    sc,CHOOSECOLS(sData,scCol),
    sv,CHOOSECOLS(sData,svCol),
    dc,XLOOKUP(di,si,sc),
    dv,XLOOKUP(di,si,sv),
    r,MAP(dc,dv,LAMBDA(c,v,
        IFNA(PERCENTRANK.INC(FILTER(sv,sc=c),
            v,significance),if_not_found))),
    r)



Get percentile rank within each cat for the selected ids, using MAP:

Filter data for cats for the selected ids
Sort the filtered data by ids
Use binary search to lookup ids (within the filtered rows)

v2: with reduced lookups
=LET(
    for_ids, E2:E4,
    data, A2:C11,
    filterd_for_ids, CHOOSEROWS(data, XMATCH(for_ids, INDEX(data, , 1))),
    all_cats, INDEX(data, , 2),
    cats_for_selected_ids, INDEX(filterd_for_ids, , 2),
    vals_for_selected_ids, INDEX(filterd_for_ids, , 3),
    filtered, SORT(
        FILTER(data, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(all_cats, cats_for_selected_ids)))
    ),
    cats, INDEX(filtered, , 2),
    vals, INDEX(filtered, , 3),
    output, MAP(
        cats_for_selected_ids,
        vals_for_selected_ids,
        LAMBDA(cat, val, PERCENTRANK.INC(FILTER(vals, cats = cat), val))
    ),
    output
)

v1
=LET(
    for_ids, E2:E4,
    data, A2:C11,
    all_ids, INDEX(data, , 1),
    all_cats, INDEX(data, , 2),
    cats_for_selected_ids, XLOOKUP(for_ids, all_ids, all_cats),
    filtered, SORT(
        FILTER(data, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(all_cats, cats_for_selected_ids)))
    ),
    ids, INDEX(filtered, , 1),
    cats, INDEX(filtered, , 2),
    vals, INDEX(filtered, , 3),
    output, MAP(
        for_ids,
        LAMBDA(x,
            PERCENTRANK.INC(
                FILTER(vals, cats = XLOOKUP(x, ids, cats, , , 2)),
                XLOOKUP(x, ids, vals, , , 2)
            )
        )
    ),
    output
)



Thanks, this is great. Do you see any ways to optimize this function? I work with large database and filter row by row slows this computation significantly

Oh, yes! :) please check the updated one and let me know. Thanks.

If it is still slow, we could get the filtered (and sorted) data separately in a different range and use it for percentile ranking.
